# Webpack ModuleFederationPlugin and HMR "Cannot set properties of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-module-federation, webpack-hmr

### Brief

Hello community!

I have been trying Webpack ModuleFederationPlugin with react and typescript in my current POC. So I have 2 applications **ChildApp** that exposes a module and a **HostApp** that consumes the exposed module.

So far I am getting the exposed module into my host application. However when I try to make changes in the host react component the HMR fails and emits error:

[image: Error on change in host component]

### What I have tried

I found sources with same issue in [Github here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/3038#issuecomment-818261210) and tried to apply the suggested solution but no success. I have tried both in **HostApp** and **ChildApp** to play around with chunks like this

```
// name of child federation config is: "editor"
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  excludeChunks: ['editor'],
   or
  chunks: ['main']
}),
```

### Code reference:

Because the application has many files, instead of polluting here with snippets I am sharing the POC repo below, still the two webpack configurations here for quick look

**`webpack.config.js` in Child app**

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8081,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            chunks: ["main"],
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "editor",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./Editor": "./src/exposed.ts",
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps,
                react: {
                    eager: true,
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps.react,
                },
                "react-dom": {
                    eager: true,
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

**`webpack.config.js` in Hostapp**

```
    module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            remotes: {
                editorMFE: "editor@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps,
                react: {
                    eager: true,
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps.react,
                },
                "react-dom": {
                    eager: true,
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

Resof the code can be found in github link below

1. [Github (recommended)](https://github.com/SiddharthaChowdhury/typescript-mfe)
2. [Codesandbox (just for code, there are different errors here)](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/SiddharthaChowdhury/typescript-mfe/main?file=%2F.codesandbox%2Ftasks.json&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h10006356khspmu39q%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B75.88928150765607%252C24.110718492343935%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h00002356kbj05pisl%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h00004356kmxicn6ok%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h10005356k6hebe0zy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsbpx3h00002356kbj05pisl%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h00002356kbj05pisl%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h00001356k6doa7xd5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.gitignore%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbqio070002356kcviwej92%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fhost%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522DIFF%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522base%2522%253A%2522HEAD%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbqk8d2004l356kjkzbiuts%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsbqk8d2004l356kjkzbiuts%2522%257D%252C%2522clsbpx3h10005356k6hebe0zy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h10005356k6hebe0zy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsbqzbel02rr356k0i31bs1g%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A8080%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbqzbel02rr356k0i31bs1g%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clsbpx3h00004356kmxicn6ok%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h00004356kmxicn6ok%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsbqnmyw00cq356k93t0gsj0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbpx3h00003356kw7ax4wag%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clsbqopem002hdlcx3mcxa3ak%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522CSB_RUN_OUTSIDE_CONTAINER%253D1%2520devcontainer%2520templates%2520apply%2520--template-id%2520%255C%2522ghcr.io%252Fdevcontainers%252Ftemplates%252Fjavascript-node%255C%2522%2520--template-args%2520%27%257B%257D%27%2520--features%2520%27%255B%255D%27%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbqnl1o00a6356kgqp82bf0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522npm%2520start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsbqnmyw00cq356k93t0gsj0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I am so close to finishing this POC just this HMR issue is one big blocker in the way.

Please help.
Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by content hashing used in output section of webpack.config.

You'll need HMR for dev purposes only. So feel free to update your config for dev env - to not use specific output settings.

1. At your host webpack config set:

```
   output: {
       uniqueName: "host"
   }
```

2. At your editor mfe webpack config set:

```
    output: {
        uniqueName: "editor",
        publicPath: "http://localhost:8081/",
    }
```

Also make sure that you have CORS set for dev-server, cause ports differ. You need it for editor mfe only.

```
    devServer: {
        port: 8081,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
          }
    },
```

p.s. As I cannot put the external links here - there is a series of module federation articles from "angular architects", so you'll find many useful things there as well.